# Radius of convergence for $\sum (xn)^n/n!$ without Stirling's approximation.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This problem is from a calculus competition.

> What is the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(xn)^n}{n!}$?

I know the answer is 1/e, but the solution uses Stirling's approximation which I am not familiar with. Is there any way to do this using the ratio test?

Comment: How about the ratio test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is:

\begin{align}
\frac{(n + 1)^{n + 1}/(n + 1)!}{n^n/n!} &= \frac{(n + 1)^{n}(n+1)/(n + 1)!}{n^n/n!} \\
&= \frac{(n + 1)^{n}/n!}{n^n/n!} \\
&= \frac{(n + 1)^{n}}{n^n} \\
&= \left( 1 + \frac1n \right)^n \\
&\to e.
\end{align}